# How to locate a specific part of a string that is (x) amount of characters to the left of this substring? (Java)

Tags: java, string

I am creating a virtual test ATM machine and I just finished the login and registration system that will bring you to a new screen with your balance, username, and a sign-out button. So far I have the button and the username finished. The way I am storing the usernames is by creating a .txt file with all of the usernames, passwords, and their balances in the format of:

```
{userName#Password#ballance}
```

EX: {admin#admin#10.0}

I am using the { and # characters as separators from the other usernames and passwords.

Reading and determining if the username and password are right is relatively easy, I creating a new string with what they typed as their username and password in the same format as in the .txt file and seeing if the inputted username and password is contained anywhere inside the file.

But I'm not sure how to read a certain amount of characters over from the username to read the balance and stop reading when they see the symbol } and output it under the balance label.

I have ABSOLUTELY no clue how I could do this and if anyone has input on this or an answer I could use it.

Comment: Passwords in a text file? But anyway ... Read a line in your text file, strip the curly braces from it, then split the resulting string by the `#` character into three parts. No need to do `subString` magic here.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I'm just experimenting with the idea of saving data in general and this test application is not built for security.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose ok thank you for the advice but how do it tell it where exactly to split

Comment: *But I'm not sure how to read a certain amount of characters over from the username to read the balance and stop reading when they see the symbol } and output it under the balance label*. I am not understanding what you mean here. Can you please elaborate with examples?

Comment: @NathanTolley Well .. simply use `String.split`.

Comment: @AKSingh what im trying to do is

1) pull a new string from the file that has the username password and balance, 
EX: {admin#admin#10.00}

2)then take that string split it up into 3 parts individually

3) be able to read the balance and display it

Comment: Do you know how to read lines from a file? If you that, then as @Seelenvirtuose mentioned `spilt("#")` should do the trick.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I now understand how to split but the last thing and probably the most important is how to pull only the username password and balance I want without knowing the ballance

Comment: @Nathan 1) `String[] split = str.split("[{#}]")` 2) `userName=split[1]` 3) `password=split[2]` 4) `balance=split[3]`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are multiple ways. The easiest one will be to use split.

```
String example = "{admin#admin#10.0}";
String [] tmp = example.split("#");
String balance = tmp[tmp.length-1].replace("}","");
System.out.println(balance);
```

This will return the balance.
This answer assumes you can read line by line.

If you can't read line by line you can do this:

```
String example = "{admin0#admin0#5.0}{admin#admin#10.0}{admin2#admin2#12.0}";
String uesrInput = "{admin#admin#"; // Create this from user input
int startIdx = example.indexOf(uesrInput) + uesrInput.length();
String subBalance = example.substring(startIdx);
int endIndx = subBalance.indexOf("}");
String balance = subBalance.substring(0, endIndx);
System.out.println(balance);
```